# Bluetooth notification and Android GUI updates

Tags: android, user-interface, bluetooth, codenameone

Using CodenameOne on Android, I've subscribed to a pedometer characteristic through Bluetooth LE.  It appears that I'm getting notifications, and I'm currently just 'writing' the data to a text area in the app as my first round of confirming the data before I parse it and present it nicely.  The issue is that the app quickly locks up, as if there is a deadlock issue between the GUI repaint and the notification events. The GUI update is done within the subscription "listener", which from what I understand, is on the GUI thread within the CodenameOne environment. The "listener" basically does at text.setText(), text.repaint(). Nothing fancy.

So, I'm not sure how to update the GUI and yet at the same time receive the notifications.  If I can fix the general lock issue, I have a button that the user can click that stops the subscription.  That button, of course, can not be used in this current state.

I looked at other questions, such as [CodenameOne background task for BluetoothLe connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917060/codenameone-background-task-for-bluetoothle-connection), but not really the same.

Any suggestions on how to "unlock" this and allow GUI updates while receiving notifications?

Comment: Can you post some snippet to show what you're doing and we could help you look into what's violating EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking at the code [here](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone/blob/master/CN1Bluethooth/src/com/codename1/cordova/CordovaCallback.java) it seems that the callback just invokes the `actionPerformed` method without going back into the EDT. I think this is something that should be fixed in the library as it clearly violates the common semantics of Codename One. I suggest wrapping your code with `callSerially()` which should solve it for now.